# Android ArrayAdapter dynamic adding more data on scrolling

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I want to add some data at scrolling time whenever scroll reaches its 5 position but getting error ArrayOutOfBoundException...

//Set adapter in MainActivity

```
  Context context = this;
  ArrayList<String> data = new  ArrayList<String> ; 
     for(int i =0; i <20;i++){
            data.add("a");
      }
  CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(
                    context,   data);
  autoComplete.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

// Custom adapter

```
public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>   {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private LogsViewHolder logViewHolder;
     ArrayList<String> data = null; 

    public customAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data) {
        super(context, 0, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int itemCount = data.size() - position;

        if (getCount()>position &&  itemCount== 5) {
            data.add("bbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
            data.add("bbbbbbb ");
            data.add("b bb");
            data.add("bbb bbbb");
            data.add("bb bbbbbb");
            data.add("b bbb");

            CustomAdapter customAdapter = (CustomSearchAdapter)  autoComplete.getAdapter();
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if (convertView == null) {
            logViewHolder = new LogsViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            logViewHolder.data = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.data);


            convertView.setTag(logViewHolder);

        } else
            logViewHolder = (LogsViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        logViewHolder.data.setText(data.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public class LogsViewHolder {
        public TextView data;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return data.size();
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Please tell me the solution how to remove that error and why that error is coming...

Comment: In which line getting `ArrayOutOfBoundException` ?

Comment: whenever i scroll drop down list then on itemCount=4 control comes in if condition of getView  and adapter will be refreshed then in getview only it is giving error ... but only after scrolling because there i am adding some more data

Comment: When adding only single item like `data.add("bbbbbbbbbbbbbb");` then?

Comment: and no need to use `CustomAdapter customAdapter = (CustomSearchAdapter)  autoComplete.getAdapter();` line just call `notifyDataSetChanged` as `customAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once try as follows Change following line

```
if (getCount()>position &&  itemCount== 5) {
```

to

```
if (position==4) {
```

**Note : If scroll reaches 5 position then in getView() the position is 4 because the index starts with 0.**

If you want to add more items at the end of listview you can try as follows

```
if (position==itemCount-1) {
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: I think that was the problem of filter in autoCompleteTextView i need to update filters also. After updating filter it is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try add [`OnScrollListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) to your `ListView` instead of adding in `getView` in your `Adapter`:

```
public void onScroll (AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){
    // check position here.
}
```

In case you want to create [EndlessAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/blob/master/demo/src/com/commonsware/cwac/endless/demo/DemoAdapter.java), look at previous link:

```
@Override
protected void appendCachedData() {
if (getWrappedAdapter().getCount()<75) {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  // Append your adapter here.
}
}
```